# How to cache AJAX content after mouseover

Tags: jquery, ajax, caching

I have primary menu like this:

```
CARS  MOTORCYCLES  TRUCKS   BUSES
```

Each of these items has own submenu containing list of makers for specific item. This list can be around 40 items long and I would like to call if after mouseover/click on primary menu item. This part is fine, no problem with that.

What I'd like to know is how can I cache pages/parts which contain list of makers. I would like to call and load submenu only first time and other times just call it from cache to prevent unnecessary data transfer.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The Ajax API provides caching by default, to enable this add the `cache` param, set to `true`. For example:

```
$.ajax({cache:true, url:'http://xyx.com', success: function(res){}});
```

Please see the [jQuery Ajax API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

Are the relevant caching headers being set on the AJAX response by the server e.g. via Expires: or Cache-Control:?